# JSON Parsing Exception: Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character '"' (code 0x22) in base64 content

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using Jackson and I'm trying to encode data in JSON & it's giving Exception.

I tried String data & byte[] data:

```
String representation of same data is here:
Bytes converted to String-------->>
{
 "appname": "aaa",
 "deviceType": "diehdcj",
 "reportedDate": "2015-05-03T15:38:45+00:00",
 "sessionId": "5366372183482-6736-23562378",
 "deviceId": "2151272389",
 "commandName" : "wqgduwusdue",
 "protocolVersion" : "0.1",
 "protocolName" : "whjs_ashk_ask",
 "data" : "false"
}
```

**Java**

> 16:50:46.065 [] [] ERROR AAATSHConnector [http-apr-10.40.120.85-80-exec-3] - JSON Parsing Exception: Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character '"' (code 0x22) in base64 content

Here's the code that does the parsing:

**Java**

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response retrieveDevicePassword(InputStream request, @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws BadRequestException, ValidationException, UnknownServerException
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DemoRequest req = null;
    DemoRequest res = null;
    byte[] data = null;
    data= IOUtils.toByteArray(request);
    DemoRequest = objectMapper.readValue(data, DemoRequest.class); //It's where the Exception occurs
```

**Java**

```
//Snippet of POJO
@XmlRootElement(name = "demoRequest") 
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) 
public class DemoRequest { 

private String commandName;

private String sessionId;

private byte[] data;

//getters & setters 

}
```

Amazingly when I try to convert same String or byte[] with a little change in the actual content "data" : "true" , it works.

Can anyone please help

Found the solution, but don't know what's it exactly doing:
If I place an escape character in front of false, like "data" : "\false" , 
it works fine.

What could be the explanation for that?

Comment: Can't give you an explanation if you don't show the code that actually tries to retrieve and parse that JSON.

Answer (score 2):

> JSON Parsing Exception: Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character '"' (code 0x22) in base64 content

The above exception comes in when the property is of type byte[] and json content is represented in String. Jackson thinks that in this case the json data is represented as base64 encoded and tries to decode it to a byte[]. If the string present in data field isn't a properly encoded base64 string, jackson raises the above exception.

Comment: how do we prevent Jackson from thinking that the String is base64?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add special setter for `data` field:

`void setData(String data) {
      this.data = data.getBytes();
}`