# How to save image and Request body in to database using springBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i am new to springBoot i am trying to save image and data in my local storage. its showing error like this Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String "\fakepath\book.jpg": Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `byte[]` from String "\fakepath\book.jpg": Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 162] (through reference chain: com.msys.smartkart.entity.Product["image"])]
please help me to learning springboot thankyou in advance.

```
@Override
public void addProduct(Product product, MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
    log.info("product details ");
    log.info(String.valueOf(product));
    byte[] image = multipartFile.getBytes();
    log.info("adding image "+image);

    Product product1 =new Product();
    product1.setProductName(product.getProductName());
    product1.setId(product.getId());
    product1.setPrice(product.getPrice());
    product1.setColor(product.getColor());
    product1.setDescription(product.getDescription());
    product1.setDetails(product.getDetails());
    product1.setImage(image);

    productRepository.save(product1);
    log.info("saved product and its image");

}
```

```
@Entity
package com.msys.smartkart.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String productName;
    String color;
    String description;
    String details;
    Integer price;
    @Lob
    byte[] image;
    @CreationTimestamp
    Date date;

}
```

Comment: Seems like the file is not being uploaded correctly - can you include your View code as well?

Answer (score 0):

that question was already asked. you can find the question and solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39708658/19096791